# How to replace multiple char in a string for password decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption, replace, str-replace, password-encryption

I want to input an encrypted password in a textbox, and press a button to have the decrypted password in another textbox.
The encryption is really simple, I have an excel table where each character has its equivalent. So basically I need to replace each character with its decrtypted equivalent, I don't know if that makes sense...

> Exemple :

```
Conversion Table : 
@ = p
# = a
) = s

Input string : @#))
Output string : pass
```

What would be the simplest way to do this ?

Comment: You just replacing characters one-to-one. Is that right?

Comment: Although that is a nice learning exercise, when going real you should avoid doing that type of algorithms and use well tested and robust ones (for example System.Security.Cryptography namespace).

Comment: Another thing, try to avoid storing the password in the database (either plain text or cyphered), it is usually not needed (in a normal use case you can store the hash of the password)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary mapping the "encrypted" characters to the "decrypted" characters:

```
var repl = new Dictionary<char, char> { {'@', 'p'}, {'#', 'a'}, {')', 's'} };
```

and evaluate it via LINQ

```
var input = "@#))";
var output = new string(input.Select(c => repl[c]).ToArray());
```

or with a loop

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in input)
{
  sb.Append(repl[c]);
}
var output = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this simple enough?

```
var map = new (char before, char after)[]
{
    ('@', 'p'), ('#', 'a'), (')', 's'), 
};

var input = "@#))";

var output = map.Aggregate(input, (a, x) => a.Replace(x.before, x.after));
```

---

Or more old school:

```
var output = input;
foreach (var m in map)
{
    output = output.Replace(m.before, m.after);
}
```

Comment: Won't work in general, if one of the `after` values also occurs as `before` value

Comment: @KlausGütter - That could be the actual design. I also used an array and not a dictionary to allow the order the be explicitly set.